# Assign JavaScript function to submit button, which should execute conditionally

Tags: javascript, post, get, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a simple form with one hidden input field, and a submit button. When the user clicks the submit button, I want it first to run a JavaScript function with a confirm() function. Depending on whether the user hits 'Ok' or 'Cancel', I want the form to submit, or to not submit.
How do I successfully assign an on-click function to a submit button, and have it work as described above?

```
function confirmDelete() {
var del = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this post?");

if (del)
  //continue and submit the form
else
  //the form should not be submitted
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="/delete/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="'.$path.'" />
</form>
```

I realize that I could scrap the form altogether and just pass the hidden variable as a GET variable to the /delete/ page, however I would prefer to use a POST variable for security reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would suffice:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, thanks! Mind explaining what effect the return in the onclick has on the execution of the submit action? Does having onclick="return false" stop any further code from being run?

Comment: `return false;` in any event handler prevents the event's default action from happening. `return true;` allows it to continue. Since `confirm` returns `true` when OK is clicked and `false` otherwise, it works perfectly in this situation.